# Apache Nifi Put Document to Couchbase

Tags: apache-nifi, couchbase

**Hi, I want to put document into couchbase bucket with nifi**.

But I got a error like this :

[image: Doc Id must not be null]

**Here is my nifi processor flow :**

[image: Here is my nifi processor flow]

**Also i specified the document id in json.**

[image: Also i specified the document id in json.]

How can i fix this

Comment: It looks like maybe the `${id}` expression is evaluating to an empty string. Where does it come from?

Comment: its come from in json and it is not empty i checked @dnault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve : should add an attribute field with EvaulateJsonPath.

[image]

specify the field in the json as an attribute in EvaulateJsonPath like this :

[image]